# How to collect turbine stream from a Standalone Turbine Stream application

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-netflix

Similar with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060679/how-to-activate-turbine-stream-endpoint-in-a-standalone-turbine-application), I created another turbine stream based application to collect hystrix stream from other applications.

Spring Boot: 2.0.4.RELEASE, Spring Cloud: Finchley.SR1

The application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableTurbineStream
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-turbine-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The application config file is:

```
server:
  port: 8989
spring:
  application:
    name: hystrix-turbine-stream

management:
  endpoints:
    web.exposure.include: '*'
```

When I explore the source codes of **@EanbleTurbineStream**, and found `TurbineController` expose a `Flux` to the  root '/' endpiont.

But when I tried to explore **http://localhost:8989** in the Hystrix Dashboard, found it did not work as expected.

**Update**: When I tried to access the turbine stream application, and got:

```
curl http://localhost:8989
data:{"type":"ping"}

data:{"type":"ping"}

data:{"type":"ping"}

data:{"type":"ping"}
```

In the application console(logging), there is some log shown as:

```
: Registering MessageChannel turbineStreamInput
```

But I can not see the there are some message sent to this channel in my [client app](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-cloud-sample/tree/master/netflix-hystrix-stream).

Here is the [sample codes of my turbine stream application](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-cloud-sample/tree/master/netflix-trubine-stream)

**Update2**: Got it worked, I used a outdated **spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-stream** (which is existed in v2.0.0M2, but not existed in the final RELEASE version) in my client app, when I used  *spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix* and *spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream* combination in the client app, it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

@Hantsy We would need more details regarding what your failures are here. I have a running Spring Boot: 2.0.4.RELEASE, Spring Cloud: Finchley.SR1 turbine stream app so I can help if you need further clarification.

For `@EnableTurbineStream` to work properly,
you'll need to add the below dependencies in your app according to documentation here 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_turbine_stream

```
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-turbine-stream
spring-boot-starter-webflux
spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit
```

(any spring-cloud-stream-* would do, raabitmq worked for me)

On the client, add a dependency to `spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream` and the `spring-cloud-starter-stream-*` of your choice.

Add the rabbitmq (in my case) configuration on your `application.properties`/`application.yml` file of your client and the turbine-stream app:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738969/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-in-hystrix-dashboard-issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You should set properties on client app project: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.hystrixStreamOutput.destination=springCloudHystrixStream`

Comment: this worked for me: spring.cloud.stream.bindings.hystrixStreamOutput.destination: turbineStreamInput